# Define a type with a subset of an object keys

Tags: typescript

I wonder how to create a type that has only a subset of keys from an object, imagine the following object:

```
const something = {
  cannary: "yellow",
  coyote: "brown",
  fox: "red",
  roses: "white",
  tulipan: "purple",
  palmera: "green"
}
```

If I defined a type like:

```
type Something = keyof typeof something
```

Autocomplete and the check type will work for all the keys, but what about if I want to accept only some of those keys like:

```
type Animal = keyof typeof {only cannary|coyote|fox}
```

is this feasible to do in typescript?

Comment: You can use `Exclude` to exclude keys you don't want: `Exclude<keyof typeof something, "roses" | "tulipan" | "palmera">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `Extract<T, U>` type is a good candidate for this. It will...

> Extract from T those types that are assignable to U

However, in your case, this still allows

```
Extract<keyof typeof something, 'cannary' | 'coyote' | 'monkey'>
```

to pass, even though `'monkey'` does not exist in `T`.

A small modification to the `Extract<T, U>` type from:

```
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
```

to

```
type ExtractExact<T, U extends T> = T extends U ? T : never;
```

forces the consumer to supply a type for `U` that **must** extend `T`.

Now:

```
type CausesTypeError = ExtractExact<keyof typeof something, 'cannary' | 'coyote' | 'monkey'>
```

will show up immediately in the IDE as something unintended:

[image]

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmUAWBLMBzGBeGA3gFAykzACGYYFATgJ4BcMARPUgDYcgDuLANCTKh6IKEmYsARrV5gBQ0gDMQAD0m0kAEwVkYsiEgiSeGcbrJQArh3QAHKpLtXadjkgukHHZLQqSsTSR5IgBfGAoIcnBoIiIoejskGABRVSg-YCg0iiyAHgAVfhgAVRgkdOCtKIKAPjwYAvLKsGrSmAB+RphmMCQANyRaAG44hKTu-DSM3OzVWbyAayRRJRhxpBA1+GQ0TCxigHJKajp6Q5gAHxhjkFFxC+vDlVVD2qIAeg+yAD0OscSyQAQhQtNNMrApukIUsVlt1oD4TsUBhsEcTjQGI8biIxEhsYcEOBlud3l9fv94oCYABhChWQwQAqAlK0WS0Brg2Y5fIk+EbJGIFH7dFUTHnK44u54glEsAkt6fb6kP5AA)

Comment:  thank you, this is what I was interested to find out, curious question, do you know if it is possible to use a filter function like startWith("c") to produce typing of those keys that start with the letter `C` 'cannary' | 'coyote' ?

Comment: @ncubica I think that `Extract<keyof typeof something, \`c${string}\`>` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As @spender pointed out, [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) will "extract" members from a set, and can be used to meet your request.

You can also use [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)

```
type AnimalsPicked = keyof Pick<typeof something, 'cannary' | 'coyote' | 'monkey'>
type AnimalsExtracted = Extract<keyof typeof something, 'cannary' | 'coyote' | 'monkey'>
```

Same result.

If you want the intermediate object type

```
type AnimalsObj = Pick<typeof something, 'cannary' | 'coyote' | 'monkey'>
```

Because you haven't actually described the larger problem you trying to solve, the following might or might not be helpful.

```
const something = {
  cannary: "yellow",
  coyote: "brown",
  fox: "red",
  roses: "white",
  tulipan: "purple",
  palmera: "green"
} as const;
const animals = (()=>{
   const {cannary,coyote,fox} = something;
   return {cannary,coyote,fox};
})();
// UI shows
// const animals: {
//   cannary: "yellow";
//   coyote: "brown";
//   fox: "red";
// }
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmUAWBLMBzGBeGA3gFAwzACGYY5ATgJ4BcMARHUgDbsgDuzANCTIg6IKEibMARjR5h+ggGYgAHhJpIAJvNIyISCBO4Yx2mFACu7dAAdKE6+ZrX2SU7fbIa5CVnVI5RAC+MOQQQpBQANxEoBEhYOgI5Oxh+AAUaQCUuAB8xKTh0IQUVLR0fKAiYnxKysH48MhomFjRBeoWNGDFlNT0FcKiSDUqgdGBmVnRREA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pick<T>` utility type

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys

```
const something = {
  cannary: 'yellow',
  coyote: 'brown',
  fox: 'red',
  roses: 'white',
  tulipan: 'purple',
  palmera: 'green',
};

// type Something = "cannary" | "coyote" | "fox" | "roses" | "tulipan" | "palmera"
type Something = keyof typeof something;

// type Animal = "cannary" | "coyote" | "fox"
type Animal = keyof Pick<typeof something, 'cannary' | 'coyote' | 'fox'>;
```